# Integrating Twilio with Angular and Node for one to one video calling

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, twilio

I want to integrate Twilio for one to one video calling in Angular and use Node in backend. I want to create a simple page and insert name and room name and join button. On submitting video starts. If another user with same room name enters, the video call between the two should start. I want to use socket for this too. How to implement it?

I tried setting up the project and connecting frontend and backend but can't work with Twilio and there is no much documentation about this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.